# Split list by element

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of 1 and 0 like this:

```
var list = new List<int>{1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1}
```

between two items, can be only one zero. 
How to split that list into sublists by 0?

Other words: if I have string like this: `string myString = "111011011110111111011101"` then it is easy to split it by 0 into few strings. 
But how to do it with list? This example shoudl produce these sublists:

```
1,1,1
1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1
1
```

so is there better way then casting each element into string, joining them and doing what I show what can be done with string ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can solve your problem by transforming the input sequence into a sequence of sequences just like the LINQ `GroupBy` does. However, in your case you are grouping on a change in the input sequence. There is perhaps the possibility of combining existing LINQ operators like `GroupBy`, `Zip` and `Skip` into something that does what you want but I think it is easier (and performs better) to create an iterator block that looks at pairs of items in the input sequence:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions {

  public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupOnChange<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, T, Boolean> changePredicate
  ) {
    if (source == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (changePredicate == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("changePredicate");

    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator()) {
      if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        yield break;
      var firstValue = enumerator.Current;
      var currentGroup = new List<T>();
      currentGroup.Add(firstValue);
      while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        var secondValue = enumerator.Current;
        var change = changePredicate(firstValue, secondValue);
        if (change) {
          yield return currentGroup;
          currentGroup = new List<T>();
        }
        currentGroup.Add(secondValue);
        firstValue = secondValue;
      }
      yield return currentGroup;
    }
  }

}
```

`GroupOnChange` will take the items in the input sequence and group them into a sequence of sequences. A new group is started when `changePredicate` is true.

You can use `GroupOnChange` to split your input sequence exactly as you want to. You then have to remove the groups that have zero as a value by using `Where`.

```
var groups = items
  .GroupOnChange((first, second) => first != second)
  .Where(group => group.First() != 0);
```

You can also use this approach if the input are class instances and you want to group by a property of that class. You then have to modify the predicate accordingly to compare the properties. (I know you need this because you asked a now deleted question that was slightly more complicated where the input sequence was not simply numbers but classes with a number property.)

Comment: Wow, you're fast... just 3 minutes to write this?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: No, kosnkov asked another more complicated question but with the same problem but there were a lot of negative comments so he deleted it. Not knowing what was happening, I worked through my solution only to discover that I had nowhere to post it. I then found this question and could answer it almost immediately.

Comment: Good thing you found this question then, it would have been a shame for your answer to go to waste ;)

Comment: @Martin this extension method is really nice

Answer (score 7):

You could write an extension method like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Split<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource splitOn, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer = null)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        return SplitIterator(source, splitOn, comparer);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> SplitIterator<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource splitOn, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
        var current = new List<TSource>();
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(item, splitOn))
            {
                if (current.Count > 0)
                {
                    yield return current;
                    current = new List<TSource>();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                current.Add(item);
            }
        }

        if (current.Count > 0)
            yield return current;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var list = new List<int>{1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1};
var result = list.Split(0);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int c = 0;
var list = new List<int>{1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1};

var res = list
    // split in groups and set their numbers
    // c is a captured variable
    .Select(x=>new {Item = x, Subgroup = x==1 ? c : c++})
    // remove zeros
    .Where(x=>x.Item!=0)
    // create groups
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Subgroup)
    // convert to format List<List<int>>
    .Select(gr=>gr.Select(w=>w.Item).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Answer (score 6):

You can just group by the index of the next zero:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 };
        var result = list.Select((e, i) => new { Element = e, Index = i })
            .Where(e => e.Element == 1)
            .GroupBy(e => list.IndexOf(0, e.Index));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something simpler:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Split(IEnumerable<int> items)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    foreach (int item in items)
        if (item == 0 && result.Any())
        {
            yield return result;
            result = new List<int>();
        }
        else
            result.Add(item);
    if (result.Any())
        yield return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code below splits by iterating over the list and storing sub-sequences of '1' in a list of lists.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SplitList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 };

            List<List<int>> splitSequences = new List<List<int>>();

            List<int> curSequence = new List<int>();

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (item == 1) {
                    curSequence.Add(item);
                } else {
                    //Only push the current sequence onto the list of sequences if it is not empty,
                    //which could happen if multiple zeroes are encountered in a row
                    if (curSequence.Count > 0) {
                        splitSequences.Add(curSequence);
                        curSequence = new List<int>();
                    }
                }
            }
            //push any final list
            if (curSequence.Count > 0)
            {
                splitSequences.Add(curSequence);
            }

            foreach (var seq in splitSequences) {
                String line = String.Join(",", seq);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            var discard = Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like ASh's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867632/8422514) most. I've used it with a slight change. There is no captured variable in "my" variant:

```
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 };

        var res = list
            // Step 1: associate every value with an index
            .Select((x, i) => (Value: x, Index: i))
            // Step 2: remove separator values
            .Where(x => x.Value != 0)
            // Step 3: adjacent items will have the same result
            // subtracting real position from the index marked during the 1st step 
            .Select((tuple, realIndex) => (tuple.Value, GroupId: tuple.Index - realIndex))
            // Step 4: group by groupId
            .GroupBy(tuple => tuple.GroupId)
            // Step 5: convert to List<List<int>>
            .Select(group => group.Select(tuple => tuple.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

**More on step 3:**

Let's say, we have 5 items with indices:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4 ]
{ 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 }
```

After filtration from the step 2, list of numbers looks next:

```
[ 0  1  3  4 ]
{ 1, 1, 1, 1 }
```

What does step 3:

```
real indices (ri):              [ 0  1  2  3 ]
indices from the 1st step (i):  [ 0  1  3  4 ]
numbers:                        { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
i - ri:                         [ 0, 0, 1, 1 ]
```

And step 4 just groups by result of the subtraction `i - ri`, so called `GroupID`.